Add divider between every child in a Column Compose Android
I would like to add a divider between every child in a Column. The number of children would be dynamic based on some condition. I have implemented the below code, could someone verify if it is right and idiomatic way of doing in Android Compose.
@Composable
fun SectionWithDividers(
    dividerModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: SectionContentScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Column {
        val items = SectionContentScope().apply(content).items
        items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            item()
            if (index < items.size - 1) {
                HorizontalDivider(
                    modifier = dividerModifier,
                    color = wfmColor.divider
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

class SectionContentScope {
    val items = mutableListOf<@Composable () -> Unit>()

    fun Item(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
        items.add(content)
    }
}

Example using it
SectionWithDividers() {
            Item {
                Text("01-01-2000", Modifier.padding(8.dp))
            }
            Item {
                Text("01-01-2000", Modifier.padding(8.dp))
            }
            Item {
                Text("01-01-2000", Modifier.padding(8.dp))
            }
        }


Your implementation is functional and achieves the goal of dynamically adding dividers between children in a Column. However, there are some points for improvement to make it more idiomatic and align better with Compose's design philosophy.
Suggestions for Improvement

Use LazyColumn for Large or Dynamic Data:-
If the number of items is large or derived dynamically, consider using LazyColumn instead of Column. LazyColumn is optimized for performance and handles item recycling.

Separate Divider Logic:-
Compose encourages separation of concerns. You can simplify the implementation by separating the logic for adding dividers.

Use Built-in Spacer for Flexibility:-
While a HorizontalDivider works, sometimes a Spacer might be more flexible if custom spacing is needed.

Modifier Placement:-
Consider making modifier an argument for each item instead of relying on a global dividerModifier for more flexibility.

Avoid Manual Indexing:-
Use built-in functions like interleave or Kotlin's zipWithNext to avoid manual index checks.


@Composable
fun SectionWithLazyDividers(
    items: List<String>, // Replace with your data type
    dividerColor: Color = Color.LightGray
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()) {
        itemsIndexed(items) { index, item ->
            Text(
                text = item,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
            )
            // Add a divider after each item except the last one
            if (index < items.size - 1) {
                Divider(
                    color = dividerColor,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}



//Usage Example
@Composable
fun Example() {
    val dates = listOf(
        "01-01-2000",
        "02-01-2000",
        "03-01-2000"
    )

    SectionWithLazyDividers(
        items = dates,
        dividerColor = Color.Gray
    )
}



That's fine :D. I see many projects from Google use that way.
